# Velocity can't find resource with webApp

Tags: java, velocity

I'm trying to create a webApp using GlashFish server and Velocity.

But i get the following error:

```
    SEVERE: ResourceManager : unable to find resource 'temp.vm' in any resource loader.
SEVERE: org.apache.velocity.exception.ResourceNotFoundException: Unable to find resource 'temp.vm'
```

velocity.proprieties:

```
resource.loader=webapp
webapp.resource.loader.class=org.apache.velocity.tools.view.WebappResourceLoader
webapp.resource.loader.path=/WEB-INF/templates/
```

Servlet:

```
 ve.setApplicationAttribute("javax.servlet.ServletContext", context);
            template = ve.getTemplate("temp.vm");
```

I am using NetBeans IDE and my temp.vm file is in /WEB-INF/templates/. The must be somethings I'm missing but I just can't get what it is.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Another option might be to use the class path resource loader and put your .vm files in `/WEB-INF/classes`.

Answer (score 2):

I just asked a similar question:

[How to load a velocity template into an EJB to be used as a mail template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175302/how-to-load-a-velocity-template-into-an-ejb-to-be-used-as-a-mail-template)

I used the ClasspathResourceLoader and created a .jar containing the templates. Put that .jar into the WEB-INF/lib folder and it should work (at least I could manage getting things up running that way).

Hope it helps :)

Regards,
Alex

Answer (score 2):

put the template in /WEB-INF/classes/template/temp.vm directory and use ve.getTemplate("template/temp.vm");

make sure to configure the resource loader to ClasspathResourceLoader.

```
<bean id="velocityEngine" class="org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactoryBean">
    <property name="velocityProperties">
    <props>
        <prop key="resource.loader">class</prop>
        <prop key="class.resource.loader.class">org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader</prop>
    </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```